# What are some best practices and tricks when passing values from a main() to an Array Stack in a different class?

Tags: java, stack, inner-classes

I am trying to pass values from my `private static void main(...)` into a class that has an array stack initialized in the constructor. I was wondering how to take the values I assign to a variable in the `main()` and `push` that value onto the array stack within this innerClass?

I know that the array stack works, I have implemented this class before without a problem, but I was only using the `arrayStack()` I had created and a `main()`. The addition of the third class is confusing me.

Without getting too deep in my code, I was hopping someone could explain (or point me to some resources) to me how to pass arguments to a stack that is initialized in a constructor, with arguments from the `main()` method of a different class (same package)?

Example of where I'm trying to get values to:

```
package program2;
public class Exec {
public Exec(DStack ds) {
    /*I have initilized an arrayStack to hold doubles (i.e. DStack). 
     * I can use ds.push()/pop()/top() etc. 
     * I cannot take the value from Calculator.java and push that value
     * here, which is what I need help understanding?
     * */
     ds.push(Calculator.i); //I would expect an error here, or the value stored in 
                           //Calculator.i to be added to the stack. Instead program
                           //terminates. 
   }
}
```

Where I would like to take the values from:

```
package program2;
public class Calculator {
public static double i;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    i=9; //I'm expecting that by using Calculator.i in the Exec class that
        //I should be able to push 'i' onto the stack. 
   }
}
```

This question goes along with a question and answer I was able to get working yesterday here: [Get answer from user input and pass to another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581898/get-answer-from-user-input-and-pass-to-another-class). There are three differences, one, I am no longer selecting an answer from the menu and performing an action. Two, I would like know how to get items on a stack versus comparing the `String` in a series of if/else statements. Lastly, I would like to know a little more detail about the nuts and bolts of this action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to completely misunderstand how an application works. When you launch your program, java executes your main method. All its instructions are executed in sequence until the end of the method is reached. If you haven't started any other thread from this method, when the last instruction in the main method has been executed, the program terminates.

In this case, the main method contains only one instruction:

```
i = 9;
```

So this instruction is executed, and since it's the last one, the program terminates. You don't even reference the Exec class anywhere, so this class isn't even loaded by the JVM.

If you want to use the Exec class, then you have to do something with is somewhere in the program. For example, you could do

```
i = 9;
DStack dstack  = new DStack();
Exec exec = new Exec(dstack);
```

Note that storing something in a public static variable in order for some other object to be able to get this value is a very poor form of parameter passing. If an Exec object needs a value to work, then it should be an argument of its constructor:

```
public Exec(DStack ds, double value) {
    ds.push(value);
}
```

and in the main method, you would use a local variable and not a public static variable:

```
double i = 9;
DStack dstack  = new DStack();
Exec exec = new Exec(dstack, i);
```

Comment: Good explanation, however I would advocate for pushing `i` on to the stack prior to passing it to the constructor for `Exec`

Comment: Thank you JB Nizet. It was confusing me because I already knew that this array stack worked at some point, but now I add initializing it in the constructor and I can't use it, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you should create an instance of the `Exec` class.  You can also create an instance of `DStack` within your program and pass it the `Exec` constructor after pushing the `double` value onto the stack.

```
package program2;
public class Calculator {
public static double i;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DStack dStack = new DStack();
    dStrack.push(i);
    Exec exec = new Exec(dStack);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing the concept of class vs. instance. You don't pass values to classes, you pass values to instances (`static` fields are sometimes called `class variables` and can make things confusing, but ignore that for now).

In a nutshell, a class is the code for that class you wrote. An instance is the actual thing that was spawned from that definition of class and actually does stuff. So the number one trick is to "instanciate" your class and create an instance. Then you pass whatever values you want to pass it like below:

```
class Foo {
    public static main(String[] args) {
        Bar bar = new Bar(); // <-- now you have an instance called bar
        bar.arrayStack.push(args[0]); // <-- Now it's passed!
    }

    class Bar {
        ArrayStack arrayStack;
        Bar(){
            arrayStack = new ArrayStack();
        }  
}
```